# When are dynamically allocated QObjects freed

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

My program does not appear to be leaking so I am curious about this. If I have initialized a subclassed QObject with new and I did not give the object a parent, when is it being destroyed? It seems to go against the specification of C++ but maybe it's possible the qt meta compiler is doing something behind the scenes.

More specifically, I am using a QThread and using moveToThread on the object with no parent (the implications of threads forces no parents). It appears that object under the thread gets destroyed when the main program finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically allocated data without lifetime management will "live" until the application is terminated.

If your concern is with your worker objects leaking, you can call `deleteLater()` on them once their work is finished, and since it is a slot, you can also connect signals to it.

Comment: So that means as long as my application finishes executing, the data dynamically allocated data with it will be freed no matter what?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't always like that, but modern OS will sweep up all the memory, allocated by a process after it is terminated. This doesn't mean you should feel like memory leaks are encouraged. But you always have at least one object without a parent - the root. Just make sure to take into consideration the lifetime management of objects without parents.

Comment: Threads don't matter, it is the process that matters, a single process can spawn many threads. All dynamically allocated data will be deleted when the process is terminated, regardless of which thread owns them. To be able to tell more, one would have to look at your source to see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: No, dynamically allocated data will live until the OS discards it. Subtle difference. If it _was_ freed when the application is terminated, then the destructors would run (like globals). So, if the leaked object manages a temporary file, the file would leak. The OS can only clean up resources when it's absolutely sure they're no longer needed - such as memory -  but not all resources are like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would answer differently. You shouldn't consider Qt to be a magic tool which changes for you general C++ design concepts. Indeed it can take care about QObject's which are children of any other QObject and their live time limited to parent's live time. But in general it's up to developer to decide when C++ objects created and then they die. It's really *bad* practice to relay on fact that all QObjects will die somewhen on application quit. Complex application with a lot of QObjects can experience heavy performance impact after certain amount of QObjects being populated.

Answering your question, any modern OS will drop all allocated areas of particular process as soon as it quits.. but having paths in application where you dont control objects you created will lead you in troubles anyway.